# VBA .FindNext() - skipping the next value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a spreadsheet that contains general ledger information for specific accounts that is structured as thus:

[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ0Zs.png)

I wanted to design a simple macro to find the cell containing "Total" and remove it, then moving to the right one column and putting "Total:" in the cell(column b).

The issue I am running into with my macro is, when I set it up to .FindNext() it picks up the "Total:" cell that just got populated as the next find. I know that I could probably handle this with an if function but I wanted to know if there was any method in which .FindNext() could skip the next result and move on accordingly.

Here is the macro in its current form. Note: This is my first attempt at making my own VBA macro.

```
Sub Macro2()

    With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells
        Set c1 = .Find("TOTAL", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c1 Is Nothing Then
        firstOne = c1.Address
        Do
            c1.Select
            ActiveCell.ClearContents
            c1.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Totals:"
            Set c1 = .FindNext(c1)

        Loop While Not c1 Is Nothing And c1.Address <> firstOne And c1.Value <> "Grand Total"
            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If someone could assist me with either getting it to skip the next value or properly offsetting it so it results in the desired effect I would be much appreciative. I also attempted to find other posts on this but did not find any with specifically this issue, I appreciate your help!

Comment: The `If` statement is probably your best bet. However, you could try to offset the start of your next search with `set c1 = .FindNext(c1.offset(0,1).Range)` to see how that works. I'm uncertain off the top of my head if the `Find` algorithm works left-right-top-bottom or a different direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit your search to only Column A:

```
Sub Macro2()

    With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A:A")
        Set c1 = .Find("TOTAL", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c1 Is Nothing Then
                firstOne = c1.Address
                Do
                    With c1
                        .ClearContents
                        .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Totals:"
                    End With
                    Set c1 = .FindNext(c1)

                Loop While Not c1 Is Nothing And c1.Address <> firstOne And c1.Value <> "Grand Total"
            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for the tip!

Can't believe it was that simple!